# libgdx generating random integer but keeps generating

Tags: java, libgdx

I used basic java to generate random integer it works , but problem is it keeps working it generates as long as the program is open.

The goal is to use the random integer to decide what image to render each time object is created.

```
public void randomGen(){
    randomInt = random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(randomInt);

}
```

this is just an example of one of ways i tried to do it.

block code

```
package com.brotiergames.ayabew;



public class Blocks  {
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private AtlasRegion sword,shield,staff,fireball,iceball;
private Random random;
private Sprite sprSword,sprShield,sprStaff,sprFireball,sprIceball;
public int randomInt;
public enum BLOCKTYPE{
    SWORD,SHIELD,FIREBALL,ICEBALL;
}
public Blocks(){
    this.atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/wizardpack.pack"));
    this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
    this.sword = atlas.findRegion("Sword");
    this.shield = atlas.findRegion("Shield");
    this.staff = atlas.findRegion("Staff");
    this.fireball = atlas.findRegion("flame");
    this.iceball = atlas.findRegion("icespell");
    this.sprSword = new Sprite(sword);
    this.sprShield = new Sprite(shield);
    this.sprStaff = new Sprite(staff);
    this.sprFireball = new Sprite(fireball);
    this.sprIceball = new Sprite(iceball);
    this.random = new Random();
    this.randomGen();

}
/*public void randomRenderofBlocks(float x,float y){
batch.begin();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        //int tempInt = randomInt;
        //int thisInt = tempInt;
        //System.out.println(thisInt);
        if   (thisInt <= 25){
            sprShield.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
            sprShield.draw(batch);
        } else if (thisInt >=26 && thisInt <=50){
            sprSword.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
            sprSword.draw(batch);
        } else if (thisInt >=51 && thisInt <=75){
            sprFireball.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
            sprFireball.draw(batch);
        } else if (thisInt >= 76){
            sprIceball.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
            sprIceball.draw(batch);
        }
        x += 92;
        //y +=92;
    }
    batch.end();
}*/
public void renderBlockX(float x , float y){
    batch.begin();
    System.out.println("O"+randomInt);
    if   (randomInt <= 25){
        sprShield.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
        sprShield.draw(batch);
        BLOCKTYPE type = BLOCKTYPE.SWORD;
    } else if (randomInt >=26 && randomInt <=50){
        sprSword.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
        sprSword.draw(batch);
        BLOCKTYPE type = BLOCKTYPE.SHIELD;
    } else if (randomInt >=51 && randomInt <=75){
        sprFireball.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
        sprFireball.draw(batch);
        BLOCKTYPE type = BLOCKTYPE.FIREBALL;
    } else if (randomInt >= 76){
        sprIceball.setBounds(x, y, 64, 64);
        sprIceball.draw(batch);
        BLOCKTYPE type = BLOCKTYPE.ICEBALL;
    }
    x += 92;
    batch.end();
    System.out.println("N"+randomInt);
}
public void oldrenderBlocks(){
    //Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    //Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    sprShield.setBounds(150, 170, 64, 64);
    sprShield.draw(batch);
    sprSword.setBounds(246, 150, 64, 64);
    sprSword.draw(batch);
    sprFireball.setBounds(342, 150, 64, 64);
    sprFireball.draw(batch);
    sprIceball.setBounds(438, 150, 64, 64);
    sprIceball.draw(batch);
    sprIceball.setBounds(530, 150, 64, 64);
    sprIceball.draw(batch);

    batch.end();
}
public void dispose(){
    atlas.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
public void randomGen(){
    randomInt = random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(randomInt);

}
```

}

then i use this class to make object array for blocks

```
public class BlockArray  {
Blocks[] blockArray = new Blocks[6];
int offsetX = 0;
public void createArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < blockArray.length; i++){
        blockArray[i] =  new Blocks();
        blockArray[i].renderBlockX(58 + offsetX, 170);
        offsetX +=92;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: you should show the code, where you call `randomGen()` ;) you cant really tell from this short code snippet where the error is.

Comment: well i called it in the constructor , and in the method that picks the blocks.

Comment: I added the code. right now when i run the game the sprites show up and disappear , usually it keep moving from image1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Put your sprites into a map. Each key is mapped to an enum. Its easy to retrieve element based on its ordinal of enum or enum itself.

```
private enum Equipment{
    Sword, Shield, Staff
}

Map<Equipment, Sprite> map = new EnumMap<Equipment,Sprite>(Equipment.class);
for(Equipment equipment : Equipment.values()){
    map.put(equipment, new Sprite(atlas.findRegion(equipment.name())));
}
```

Retrieve your image

```
private Random random = new Random();

private Sprite getRandomImage(){
    Equipment[] values = Equipment.values();
    return map.get(values[random.nextInt(values.length)]);
}
```

Comment: thanks i need to able to tell which type of block it is to see what it counters. I am assuming sword is 0 and so on?

Comment: See my updated answer, you are able to retrieve image based on a string, an enum, or enum ordinal.

Comment: The problem is fixed.

Comment: I forgot to add map.get(), make sure that map is a field and everything should work.

Comment: Well, I need to see a stracktrace. Make sure your enums match the names of your textures i.e. In my example, I have textures  `Sword`, `Shield` and `Staff`

Comment: Yeah its Sword , Shield , flame , icespell , there are 2 other textures in pack but i want them to be ignored.

Comment: If you are getting NPEs I have to see the stacktrace.